# Spring Data JPA doesn't specify lower keyword in method names

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I need to lowercase all emails when querying my table, but the documentation specifies only method-name-keyowrd for `UPPER()`:

IgnoreCase  findByFirstnameIgnoreCase   … where UPPER(x.firstame) = UPPER(?1)

How the `LOWER()` could be used?
I have debug it and can see that `PredicateBuilder` doesn't seem to be considering it.

Are you aware if that is a limitation? Or could this be achieved in different way?

Comment: Why you can't use `findByFirstNameIgnoreCase(...)`?

Comment: @user2901244 If you got your question, `findXXXByIgnoreCase` by default uses `UPPER...`. Not sure, but did you give a try with custom query using `@Query` annotation and specifying `SELECT .... LOWER(x.fistname)= LOWER(?1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [Spring JPA reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation),  `findXXXByIgnoreCase(...)` by default uses `UPPER(...)` to perform case insensitive search.

To force it to use `LOWER` keyword we can use a custom query with `@Query` annotation and specifying `SELECT .... LOWER(email)= LOWER(?1)`.

In my case I have used custom query as below to force it to use `LOWER` keyword for `email` column:

```
@Query("SELECT p from Person p where LOWER(email) = LOWER(?1)")
List<Person> findByEmailIgnoreCase(@Param("email") String email);
```

and this resulted in creating following query:

```
Hibernate: select person0_.id as id1_0_, person0_.email as email2_0_, person0_.first_name as first_na3_0_, person0_.last_name as last_nam4_0_ from person person0_ where lower(person0_.email)=lower(?)
```

This should help the query to use the function index i.e., `LOWER(email)`.

Comment: thanks, I went for custom query, which for now fixes my problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Data JPA docs say this about case sensitivy of properties:

```
// Enabling ignoring case for an individual property
List<Person> findByLastnameIgnoreCase(String lastname);

// Enabling ignoring case for all suitable properties
List<Person> findByLastnameAndFirstnameAllIgnoreCase(String lastname, String firstname);
```

Using `IgnoreCase` in your method name will automatically generate a query which is case insensitiv for one or all specified properties.

Otherwise you always have the possibility to specify a custom query for your method by annotating it like this:

```
@Query("select u from User u")
Stream<User> findAllByCustomQueryAndStream();
```

By using the `@Query` annotation you can use the plain old JPQL to query your database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

However, JPA always generates:
     upper(user0_.EMAIL)=upper(?) 

when ignore case keyword is used.

And I have existing index on lower(email), which i would like to make use of.

Comment: Then you need to define your own query by using the `@Query` annotation: `@Query("SELECT e FROM  employee where LOWER(email) = LOWER(?1)")`

Comment: Yes, I did that. Works well.Thanks